# Basic, Frame by Frame Sprite animation using Animator class

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a simple sprite sheet that I'm using in a Unity project:

[image: Say hi to Wizzy]

It has frames for walking and standing in each of four directions.  I've cut the image up using Unity's Sprite Editor and made a separate `Animation` object for each series, all of which fit neatly into a single animation controller:

[image]
[image]

I've added the animation controller to an `Animator` component on a `GameObject` in my scene.  This is where I start running into trouble.  **I can't for the life of me figure out how to change between the animations in my code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to create the connections between your animations in a script. What you do is you create the connections in the Animator and set up variables for if you are standing or walking and in which direction you are going. Then you just edit these variables in a script and the Animator takes care of chosing the right animation.

This video shows it in action: [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5iF9V6RExQ)

(you see the connections and in the bottom left the variables he set up)

Quick google of "mechanim 2d tutorial" gives you: [Tutorial](http://pixelnest.io/tutorials/2d-game-unity/animations-2/)

edit:

Too long for a comment :)

Basically what i would do is create 2 variables, one bool named "Standing" and one Integer named "Direction". Then you make one connection from AnyState to every other state you have(Rightclick on AnyState to make the transitions). Maybe order them in a circle around AnyState.

After this, click on the connections and in the Inspector set the conditions by chosing "Standing", then add one more and set it to "Direction" "Equals" and the number for the direction.

Then in your script somewhere in your Update function you might have something like:

```
private readonly int UP = 0;

...

if(speed.magnitude > 0.0f)
    Animator.SetBool("Standing", false);
else
    Animator.SetBool("Standing", true);


if( Condition for walking up? )
    Animator.SetInteger("Direction", UP);
if( Condition for walking down? )
    Animator.SetInteger("Direction", DOWN);
...
```

this might not work directly, but you get the idea. You might want to use a switch for the direction depending on how you set it up.

Comment: I guess setting up connections and letting the `Animator` handle which plays when felt a little excessive for my requirements.  Right now I'm using `Animator.CrossFade()`, is that actually creating new connections on the fly?  I was hoping to avoid having to do that at all since, in reality, my animations don't have any complex relationships to eachother.  They're just in state A, or B, or whatever; I was hoping to have a single place to store them all, and swap between them quickly.

Comment: I dont think CrossFade actually creates connections, but by using that you kinda do it manually :) I guess if its working for you just use it. I think it just feels excessive to you because you havent done it before. Actually setting it up for your needs is only a couple of clicks and then 2 lines of code in your script to change the variables with something like Animator.SetBool("Walking", true);

Comment: I'll def give it a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why even use code? Just hook it all up in the Animator using parameters and just change the parameters as needed.

Comment: This was sort of one of those questions I for myself just by figuring out how to word (thus the wiki answer).  Could you expand on this answer a bit?

Comment: It's best if you check out tutorials for the details, but basically: the Animator screen has a number of states, and each has an animation associated with it; so for example, WalkRight would be your walking right animation. Then in the Animator, you can create transitions between these states, which will be based on certain conditions you also set in the Animator. These conditions are simple int/bool/whatever parameters that you can change from code; change the parameter and the Animator will transition from one state to the other.

Comment: Huh, I see.  I def have more information to go out and look for tutorials with, now; I guess the big problem for me was searching on the wrong terms.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The [`Animator.CrossFade`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFade.html) function will achieve the desired results:

**C#:**

```
Animator animator = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
animator.CrossFade("WizzyWalkDown", 0);
```

It may seem a little excessive, or counter-intuitive, but remember that the `AnimationController` class was built to make transitions between animations easy.  It can still very much be used for simpler animation types like this, though!